# Getting (NULL) when sending contents of one View label to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have been trying to create a score system that once the timer ends a new view appears and prints out the final score. My timer works properly when I run and so does the initial score as I get the correct answer. However when I try to update my second view controller's view final score label to what ever the last score received after the timer hit 0, my second view controller's final score label prints out a 0 or if I change it to a string a (null).

Below is my code so you can see what is going on.

FirstViewController .m

Okay so basically to summarize what I have below are 4 methods:

1. timerRun(holds time loop and condition for ending time),
2. setTimer (basically sets the timer to initial length),
3. detectDrawing(this one detects drawing recognition and if it matches the templates        provided gives the score label a score of GAME_SCORE or GAME_SCORE BONUS. Once they get a   score)
4. viewDidLoad(basically calls my timer and initially set the gameScore to 0)

Now I didn't want to burden everyone with too much useless code but the reason I then call 
[viewDidAppear] method after the score was it will loop my game each time until the time ends.

Ok sorry for the long windiness.

```
-(void)timerRun
{
self.secondsCount--;
int seconds = self.secondsCount;

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",seconds];
self.timerLabel.text = timerOutput;

if(self.secondsCount == 0)
{
[self.gameCountDownTimer invalidate];


self.objSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController." bundle:nil];

self.finalScore =self.gameScore;

NSLog(@"THE FINAL_CURRENT SCORE IS %d!!!!!!!!!!!!!",self.finalScore);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondViewScreen" sender:self];


}



}

-(void)setTimer
{
self.secondsCount = TIMER_LENGTH;
self.gameCountDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
- (void)DetectDrawing:(DrawingGameGlyphDetectorView*)theView glyphDetected:(WTMGlyph *)glyph withScore:(float)score
{
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:10];

if (score < GESTURE_SCORE_THRESHOLD)
return;
else if([glyph.name isEqualToString:convertAnswer])
{
NSLog(@"WOOOOOOOO!HOOOOOO!~~~");

self.gameScore += GAME_SCORE;

if(self.answer > number)
{
self.gameScore += GAME_SCORE_BONUS;

}
self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%i",self.gameScore];
self.objSecondView.finalScore = self.scoreLabel.text;
[self viewDidAppear:YES];
}

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self setTimer];
self.gameScore = 0;


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

self.objFirstView = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController."    bundle:nil];

self.finalScoreText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.objFirstView.finalScore];

    NSLog(@"NEW VIEW!!!!!! AND THE  FINAL SCORE IS!!!! %i",self.objFirstView.finalScore);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to allocate a new "SecondViewController". Segue will do that for you.
Basically you dont want to  have references from one ViewController to the other. This most likely will create retain cycles.

All you need to do is:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  SecondViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
  dest.finalScoreText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.gamescore];
}
```

Comment: Hmm I still can't seem to get it to not display 0. Just making sure, I place that prepareForSegue method inside my FirstViewController and do I need to call anything in my Second? and I was trying to read documentation on that method and was wondering if I need to setup segue at all through storyboard.